# Recursively generate a flat, indexed array of all values/leafnodes from a multidimensional array of unknown depth

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, traversal

*N* in this question means any arbitrary number of any size and is not necessarily (but could be) the same. I have an array with N number of key => value pairs. These key => value pairs can also contain another array of size N with N number of key => value pairs. This array can be of N depth, meaning any key => value pair in the array could map to another array.

How do I get all the values of this array (storing them in a new, 1 dimensional array), ignoring the keys in the key => value pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array-walk-recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

> **rob at yurkowski dot net** 26-Oct-2010
> 06:16
>
> If you don't really particularly
> care about the keys of an array, you
> can capture all values quite simply:

```
$sample = array(
    'dog' => 'woof',
    'cat' => array(
        'angry' => 'hiss',
        'happy' => 'purr'
    ),
    'aardvark' => 'kssksskss'
);

$output = array();

// Push all $val onto $output. 
array_walk_recursive($sample, create_function('$val, $key, $obj', 'array_push($obj, $val);'), &$output);
// Printing echo nl2br(print_r($output, true));

/*
 * Array
 * (
 *  [0] => woof
 *  [1] => hiss
 *  [2] => purr
 *  [3] => kssksskss
 * )
 */
```

Comment: While this does seem to be the best answer, my only qualms are that this functionality is only supported by PHP >=5.3 . But still this would be the best way to do it.

Comment: edit to my previous comment, inline PHP and functions are only supported by PHP >=5.3 . If this function used just a reference to a function, it would work in older versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could do smt like this:

```
$output = array();

function genArray( $arr ) {
    global $output;
    foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
        if( is_array($val) ) 
            genArray( $val );
        else
            output[$key] = $val;
    }
}

genArray( $myArray );
```

Instead of recursion, using global variable and function, it could be done via loops, but this is just a general idea, and probably needs a little of your attention, anyway. That should be a good thing :)

Comment: With an older version of PHP, this is the best solution. I would remove the global variable and just return it in the function though.

Comment: @bmarti44: return an array? or array element?

Comment: Ah, I see you can't return it in this case. That would be returning an array element, you are correct.

Comment: @bmarti44: i do think that there is a more elegant solution :). maybe using passing args by reference?

Comment: Yes, be specifying a second empty array and passing it by reference you would be able to remove the need of the global variable. That would most likely be the best answer.